# What cloth simulation settings can stop my shirt from sliding down my character?

Tags: cloth-simulation

Working on creating clothes with cloth simulation and different poses, and am having trouble with my shirt collar stretching out when my character changes poses and having the shirt slide off the character from the collar as can be seen in [this video.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qcC2bgs2qSzkV8-26pyb1LQZsapv_ONe/view?usp=sharing) What cloth simulation settings can help me fix this problem and keep my shirt mesh on my character? the blend files can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1c-iILCd5u_9OFhesL9l0HqpGZD0T_YUF?usp=sharing) if needed. Thanks, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Put the *Armature* modifier on the top of your modifier stack and it seems to work:

[image]

Comment: The shirt sits properly on T-Pose for me as well, I only get the 'sliding shirt' problem when the character switches poses. Although its funny you mentioned the armature thing, I just made a post last night about self collisions with this same file and that was the solution. Just gotta fix the collar and I should be good to go lol

Comment: It's hard for me to test properly as my computer is rather slow, but I see that you haven't set any pin group for your shirt, you can't count on the physics only, create a pin group, maybe watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbyfuW5Aocg